# Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 Web Services and Mailbox Managment - CRM development

Tags: .net, exchange-server, crm, exchangewebservices

I’m a programmer working on a CRM project.

I wanted to know if there’s a way to configure some kind of a “large mailbox” on Ms Exchange 2007 to which all incoming and outgoing messages to the company goes through, and stay (like some kind of a shortcut – I don’t want to waste double disk space for this mailbox)

We are planning a CRM system which suppose to use EWS to search in this “large mailbox” for all incoming and outgoing of a customer and display them on customer profile form (.net)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mailbox is called "Journal Mailbox", looks exactly like an ordinary mailbox from the API point of view. By default it's off and you must enable it. Instructions are totally different depending on Exchange Server version (2003, 2007 or 2010). The mailbox will contain exact copies of all the emails going in/out/inside the company, however they're not just references (if you understand the email flow process, you can figure out why they are not possible to have). I suppose your CRM system can periodically check the mailbox, index messages, and delete them from the journal.

I'd suggest you consult with Exchange administrator in your company, because it may already be enabled.

P.S. Exchange is optimizing it's database store not to store duplicate messages (at least beginning from 2003) so you shouldn't really worry about that.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to configure my Exchange 2007 server for EWS without success, I keep getting access denied errors when trying to use the EWS, any help?

Comment: How exactly are you authenticating across a mailbox? There are different types of access policies in EWS.